# Question about filter

Tags: power-electronics, filter, signal-processing, active-filter, passive-filter

I'm studying filter. I saw the filter in book. Therefore, I designed the circuit in the LTSpice for understanding the circuit. However, I do not clearly understand whether the filter is bandpass or not. I have more question about this topic. How can I design this circuit in active filter (Sallen-Key etc.)?

Thanks for your advance support.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you understand what "bandpass" means?

Comment: It is, but it doesn't have any damping on L1+C2, that's why you see that peak. Since this is an LC filter, it will have to see both an input and an output resistance, or impedance, of some sort -- which you have not added. If in doubt, either calculate the transfer function, or judge how the states are disposed in the circuit: 2 caps and one inductor, where they are placed, what effect they have, etc. Don't just throw elements and simulate blindly, try to understand what everythying does.

Comment: @user1850479 the filter that passes the frequencies within certain ranges.

Comment: It definitely passes a limited range of frequencies but not 0 or infinity, although it is not very flat due to the resonant peak.  That makes it a (possibly not very good) bandpass filter.

Comment: @user1850479 the band-pass part IS the resonant peak and it would be a great BP filter in some applications but, we're not here to discuss those applications LOL

Comment: @Andyaka Thank u very much

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer...

Convert this to a simple bandpass filter (BPF), which means get rid of the input capacitor. A simple BPF is shown in the schematic below.

[image: schematic]

A simple BPF can be easily analyzed.

The center frequency is:
$$  f_o = {1 \over {2 \pi \sqrt{LC}}} $$
For your circuit \$ f_o = 3003 \text{ Hz} \$

The bandwidth is calculated from the low-pass prototype which is the corner frequency formed by R1 and C1 (refer to references in above schematic). The corner frequency is
$$ f_c = BW_{HPF} = {1 \over {2 \pi R C}}  $$
For your circuit \$ BW = 168 \text{ Hz} \$

In LTspice, this all checks out.

When designing a BPF, you normally start with the low-pass prototype, scale the components, then resonate the reactive devices at the desired center frequency.

Due to the relatively narrow bandwidth, you also need to take in to consideration the non-ideal makeup of the inductor and capacitor. In practice, the bandwidth will be wider and the gain will be less than the ideal calculations.

In your example, you have a 10nF capacitor on the input. This complicates the analysis, but just eyeballing it, the reactance of the input capacitor is around 5k, thus, you will get a very narrow bandwidth in the order of a few Hz.

If you want to learn about RLC filters I suggest reading "Simplified Modern Filter Design" by Philip Geffe. It's an old book (1963) that can be found in some university technical libraries.